# Simple query condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a Query - - < This Is a valid Query >

```
'SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE city= ?
ORDER BY name ' [Keyname]
```

I am using this queried condition :: i am passing the Keyname as params from client to this sql query

**This works & i get the required result BUT**

If i pass nothing say `null` comes from client as param value for Keyname......... this query fails

- how can i make the better query ... so that even if `null` comes ....
  `ORDER BY` condition  is satisfied

Or

- R there other solution i need to look for
- If so ... what is it ?

***Hope i am clear***

### [EDIT]

***CASE1***:: for the url

```
http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=Pune
```

my told query satisfies::

But

```
http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=
```

my query fails, my sql query is expecting a `Key` for `http://54.218.73.244:7005/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/` ..... if i pass nothing my query dosent get me a result..
.
what i am trying to see is even if i get nothing as `key` ORDER BY condition must be met ...

**IF I PASS A KEY VALUE**

[image]

**IF I DONT PASS A KEY VALUE**

[image]

**You can clearly see i am not able to fetch results from database (Empty JSON)**

Comment: Is it `ORDER BY Keyname` or is it `ORDER BY name` ?

Comment: What order do you want among null-s/non-null-s? Nulls come last? What order should be among null-s?

Comment: _this query fails_ does not compute. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @ sarwar026 ... @ Alma Do Mundo ... @geomagas ..... I have updated the question ... please have a look at it

Comment: This should be done in the higher-level language that builds this query and sends it for execution. Please specify your client application's language.

Comment: Client ... I am using Android . java ....i am using a get request ...

Comment: Use tags related to your application level code. That's probably more relevant.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. It's `WHERE`, not `ORDER BY`, where the condition is specified. And your `WHERE` condition is `city = ?`. When `Key` is set, the `?` evaluates to that value and `city` is matched against it. Now, if `Key` is not set, *what value* should the `city` column be matched against? In other words, what cities should the query return if `Key` is not set?

Answer (score 3):

This question doesn't have anything to do with MySQL. This is 100% your high level language. The `null` value the `[Keyname]` has is a `null` value in the language you're using to create the string that will be the final query.

The simplest solution will be not to assign `null` to your `[Keyname]` variable but rather an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this:

```
ORDER BY name CASE WHEN Keyname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(',', Keyname) END
```

I am not sure whether the syntax is fine or not. But what I expect here to append `empty` string when `Keyname` is `null` and to append the `Keyname` with a `comma (,)`. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question ... please have a look at it .... can i use your answer to that scenario .. i have given better explanation

Comment: Welcome. btw, when the key is null/empty, then by which column you want to sort the result? Or don't you sort it at all in that case?

Comment: When the key is null .... I want to order by colum called 'name' .... as i have shown in the question ... that condition remains unchanged

Comment: I've update my answer. Please see whether it works or not! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other option is using function `ISNULL`

```
ISNULL(Keyname, '');
```